# Error with "to_sql" on Rails 3 Beta 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm testing Rails 3 beta 4 on Ruby 1.9.2-head, and when I start a
console and do:

```
Game.first.to_sql
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I know it can find the Game record, because when I type:

```
Game.first
```

it returns:

```
=> #<Game id: 1, name: "Galaga", created_at: "2010-06-19 11:02:37",
updated_at: "2010-06-19 11:02:37">
```

What am I missing? I just want to make the to_sql work in a very simple
case.

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `Game.first` you are returning a `Game` object, not a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object as you are expecting.

To do what you're trying to do, you'll need to do:

```
Game.limit(1).to_sql
```

This lets you run it without `to_sql` and return the object as you expected it, although it will be in an array, which then you can run `.first` on it like you wanted anyways.

```
irb(main):004:0> Game.limit(1).to_sql
=> "SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` LIMIT 1"
irb(main):005:0> Game.limit(1).class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
irb(main):006:0> Game.limit(1)
=> [#<Game id: 1, name: "Galaga", created_at: "2010-06-19 11:02:37", updated_at: "2010-06-19 11:02:37">]
irb(main):007:0> Game.limit(1).first
=> #<Game id: 1, name: "Galaga", created_at: "2010-06-19 11:02:37", updated_at: "2010-06-19 11:02:37">
```

When you dig into the source, when you run `.first` on an ActiveRecord::Relation it runs the following (which is the same as I showed you):

```
def find_first
  if loaded?
    @records.first
  else
    @first ||= limit(1).to_a[0]
  end
end
```

Comment: It works! I was affraid that my dev machine was not setup correctly with Rails or Ruby. Like some module was missing or something. I see not that I was just doing it wrong.

Now I've got to get my head around the differences between a query definition and the model that comes from it.  I'll get there. Thanks for the help.